# Undefined variable (Can not find variable in view)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass a variable from the controller to the view, but it is displaying the following message:

> Undefined variable.

#### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuizController extends Controller
{
public function getUrl($url = null) {
    $bandeira = '1';
    $bandeira2 = '2';

    if ($url == '1') {

        return view('quiz')->with($bandeira);

    } elseif ($url == '2') {

        return view('quiz')->with($bandeira2);

    } else {
        return view('home');

    }
  }
}
```

#### View

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Copa do Mundo 2018</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap">

<h1>Quiz Copa do Mundo 2018</h1>

<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">

    <ol>

        <li>

            <h3> ?</h3>
            @if($bandeira == '1')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/espanha.jpg') }}" alt=""/>
            @elseif($bandeira == '2') 
                <img src="{{ asset('img/argentina.jpg') }}" alt=""/>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as 
 `<?php echo $key; ?>`.

Correction of your code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuizController extends Controller
{
public function getUrl($url = null) {

   $data_to_view['bandeira'] = url;

    if ($url != null) {

        return view('quiz')->with($data_to_view);

    } else {
        return view('home');

    }
  }
}
```

In your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Copa do Mundo 2018</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap">

<h1>Quiz Copa do Mundo 2018</h1>

<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">

    <ol>

        <li>

            <h3> ?</h3>
            @if($bandeira == '1')
                <img src="{{ asset('img/espanha.jpg') }}" alt=""/>
            @elseif($bandeira == '2') 
                <img src="{{ asset('img/argentina.jpg') }}" alt=""/>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

write your variable like this

```
   $bandeira['bandeira'] = 1;
   return view('quiz')->with($bandeira);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your getUrl method just like this 
`return view('home', ['bandeira' => $url]);` and no if statement required

Answer (score -1):

change your view page

```
<?php 
      if(isset($bandeira) && $bandeira==1)
        {
        // your code here.... 
       } 
      else if(isset($bandeira) && $bandeira==2) 
       { 
         // your code here.... 
       }

    ?>
```

**I think it is helpful for you**